# Do you know the SharePoint 2016 "Zombie ItemID Cache Bug"?

Tags: javascript, ajax, sharepoint

After migrating various SharePoint 2013 JavaScript apps to SharePoint 2016, I had to look at an strange phenomenon of the SharePoint 2016 Rest API:

assume you have 2 ajax calls

1. Upload a file --> returns spFile
2. get the list item for the uploaded file --> returns spItem

   ```
   jQuery.ajax({
       url: "/sites/mysite/_api/web/getFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/mySite/myLibrary')/files/add(overwrite=true, url='test1.txt')",
       type: "POST",
       data: params.arraybuffer,
       processData: false,
       headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose", "X-RequestDigest": params.digest, "X-HTTP-Method": "POST","If-Match": "*" },
       success: function (file) {
           //get listItem for uploaded file
           jQuery.ajax({
               url: file.d.ListItemAllFields.__deferred.uri,
               type: "GET",
               headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
               success: function (result) {
                   //after first upload: OK
                   var id = result.d.ID;
               }
           });
       }
   });
   ```

If the file has not yet existed under this URL, everything is OK. SharePoint creates a new list item, and you will get the new item with the correct ID in the second call - lets assume we get ID 1.

If a file with the same name was already existing under this url and later it was deleted, SharePoint generates a new item with a new ID. This is as expected. 
BUT: In this case, the SharePoint Rest API returns the wrong list item. Instead of the new created list item (ID 2), you will get the old deleted item with ID 1.

In SharePoint 2013, this error does not occur. In SharePoint 2016 - this error only occurs in case of the same browser context for ajax call 1 and ajax call 2. Typically you are affected by this error, if you upload a file und at the same time you will update some meta values.

It seems to be a bug in SharePoint 2016. I suppose, MS have implemented a more strictly cache algorithm and was getting over the target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until MS will fix this bug, I have found a workaround:

1. Upload your file under a temporary name - jQuery.Guid.New() + myExtension
2. get the new item for your uploaded file
3. send a call to delete an possibly existing file with the real target name
4. rename your uploaded file into the real target name

   ```
                   var real_filename = 'test1.txt';
                   var temp_filename = jQuery.Guid.New() + '.txt';
                   // upload temp_filename instead real filename - fixes SharePoint 2016 ZombieId CacheBug
                   jQuery.ajax({
                       url: "/sites/mySite/_api/web/getFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/mySite/myLibrary')/files/add(overwrite=true, url='" + temp_filename + "')",
                       type: "POST",
                       data: params.arraybuffer,
                       processData: false,
                       headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose", "X-RequestDigest": params.digest, "X-HTTP-Method": "POST","If-Match": "*" },
                       success: function (file) {
                           //delete a possiblly existing file with real target name
                           jQuery.ajax({
                               url: "/sites/mySite/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/mySite/myLibrary/" + real_filename + "')",
                               type: "POST",
                               processData: false,
                               headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose", "X-RequestDigest": params.digest, "X-HTTP-Method": "DELETE", "If-Match": "*" },
                               success: function () {
                                   //target file was existing
                                   finalize(file);
                               },
                               error: function () {
                                   //target file was not existing
                                   finalize(file);
                               }
                           });
                       }
                   });
                   function finalize(file) {
                       //get listItem for uploaded file
                       jQuery.ajax({
                           url: file.d.ListItemAllFields.__deferred.uri,
                           type: "GET",
                           headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
                           success: function (result) {
                               var spItem = result.d;
                               //rename the uploaded file
                               jQuery.ajax({
                                   url: spItem.__metadata.uri,
                                   type: "POST",
                                   data: JSON.stringify({ __metadata: { 'type': spItem.__metadata.type }, FileLeafRef: real_filename }),
                                   headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose", "X-RequestDigest": params.digest, "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose", "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE", "If-Match": "*" },
                                   success: function () {
                                       //file was renamed
                                       spItem.FileLeafRef = real_filename;
                                       defer.resolve(spItem);
                                   },
                                   error: function (e) {
                                       //something went wrong
                                       defer.resolve(null, e);
                                   }
                               });
                           }
                       });
                   }
   ```